Elasticsearch: How count the total number of terms aggregated for each field in the same request
I am getting an aggregated list of plays in the data with this request
GET /shakespeare/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "plays": {
      "terms": { "field": "play_name",
      "order": { "_key": "asc" },
      "size": 200  
      }
    }
  }

and the total number of plays with this request
GET /shakespeare/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "terms_count": {
      "cardinality": { "field": "play_name"}
    }
  }
}

Is there a way to get the total number of terms for each of the fields in one request?
GET /shakespeare/_mapping

gives
{
  "shakespeare": {
    "mappings": {
      "_meta": {
        "created_by": "file-data-visualizer"
      },
      "properties": {
        "index": {
          "properties": {
            "_id": {
              "type": "long"
            },
            "_index": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "line_id": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "line_number": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "play_name": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "speaker": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "speech_number": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "text_entry": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "type": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

For example how can I get all these 3 fields: speaker, line_number and play_name in the same request.

Do you mean that above two request you want to combined as single request ? or do you want to add other fields as well as cardinality aggregation.

As per the above example I want all these 3: speaker, line_number and play_name in the same request.

You can check below answer, same way you can add N number of aggregation in single request.

You can perform multiple aggregation in the same _search request.
GET /shakespeare/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "plays": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "play_name"
      }
    },
    "terms_count": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "play_name"
      }
    }
  }
}


  #response
  "aggregations": {
    "terms_count": {
      "value": 2
    },
    "plays": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "Pericles",
          "doc_count": 3
        },
        {
          "key": "Henry IV",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }



is it posible to get speaker, line_number and play_name in the same request?

check the composite aggregation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html

I just tinkered with it and it seems that if I just add the fields one after another like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78510451/1577343
it just works

Thanks for your feedback, yes you can use multiple aggregation in the same request like I mentioned in the response. Happy to hear you find the solution.

I just checked and elastic supports adding subsequent, fields in the same object one after another:
GET /shakespeare/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "plays": {
      "cardinality": { "field": "play_name"}
    },
    "speeches": {
      "cardinality": { "field": "speech_number"}
    },
    "speakers": {
      "cardinality": { "field": "speaker"}
    },
    "lines": {
      "cardinality": { "field": "line_id"}
    }
  }
}

